# What does "parsimonious representation" mean in the context of speech recognition?

Tags: speech-recognition

I was studying about LPC (Linear Predictive coding) and in this topic the author was explaining the reasons why LPC is used widely for speech recognition system. One reason he gave was this:

> The way in which LPC is applied to the analysis of speech signals leads to a reasonable source-vocal tract separation. As a result, a parsimonious representation of the vocal tract characteristics becomes possible

What is parsimonious representation of the vocal tract characteristics?

Comment: it means that the relevant properties of the vocal tract are described with relatively few parameter settings, or (equivalently) that the vocal tract so described has relatively few degrees of freedom.

Comment: It's part of the mathematical esthetics that permeates many sciences — basically recursive application of Occam's Razor to eliminate all but totally independent (if possible, orthogonal) parameters.